# Docker container unable to start using palantir dockerRun in build.gradle

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile, build.gradle

For some reason, after using palantir plugin and executing `dockerRun`, the docker container does not start. I do not see the docker container running using `docker ps`. The results are empty. `dockerRun` exits with below which is correct I guess, however, `docker ps` shows no results and when I try hitting the url at 8080, the webserver is not started.

```
./gradlew dockerRun
> Task :dockerRun
70a0d032b214240e3ad331f0f20cf6b92912f8a9877bd77a986cea9d92c2a9c5
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I am using the standard palantir `docker` and `dockerRun` tasks in `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.22.1"
    id "com.palantir.docker-run" version "0.22.1"
}

...

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

docker {
    name "${project.name}:${project.version}"
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
    copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*","springreadyapp.jar")
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "springreadyapp.jar"])
    files 'springreadyapp.jar'
}

dockerRun {
    name "${project.name}"
    image "${project.name}:${project.version}"
    ports '8080:8080'
    env 'KEY': 'abcdefgh'
    clean true
}
```

The `Dockerfile` looks like below

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Are you able to start the container without using `sudo`. If not, then it may be a permission issue. In that case check [here](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker/issues/188)

Comment: What does the `docker logs <container id>` command display?

Comment: @AdilB Doing `docker ps` does not show any container id as guess since container is not started may be

Comment: @kaushik I tried running manually `docker run myapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and it returns following
`no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar`

Comment: Same error Im also facing. Have you find any solution?

Comment: @Az.MaYo My source jar file path while copying it to app.jar was incorrect.

Comment: I resolved the issue also, let me add my answer,

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with same issue at the end I did below changes and it works perfectly fine.

Dockefile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=build/libs/*.jar
RUN echo ${DEPENDENCY}
COPY ${DEPENDENCY} /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker task:

```
docker {
    name = "${project.name}"
    copySpec.from("build").into("build")
    setDockerfile(file("Dockerfile"))
}
```